# Params not showing file field key when image is removed using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a requirement where there is a need to remove the uploaded image.

Currently, using jQuery to remove image using the below mentioned code;

```
$(".image_remove").click(function(){
  $("#venue_pic").attr({src: null,
    alt: ""});
});
```

Also used this

```
$(".image_remove").click(function(){
  $("#venue_pic").val('');  
});
```

But params won't show the file field attribute as nil or ""(blank string).

I know that using carrierwave's remove_attribute the same can be done, but that would include an extra ajax call.

But I want to manage it via params, so that if there is any change in file field tag then the value would be updated correspondingly.

So how to update(remove) image in rails and why is params not detecting empty value in file field type input.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```js
$(function(){
  $(".deleteButton").on("click", function(){
    $newInput = $(".picture").clone()
    $(".picture").remove()
    $(".pictureWrapper").append(
      $("<input type='file'>").addClass($newInput.attr("class")).attr("name", $newInput.attr("name"))
      //or
      //$("<input type='file' name='picture' class='picture'>")
    )
  })
})
```

```css
.deleteButton {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="pictureWrapper">
  <input type="file" name="picture" class="picture">
</div>
<div class="deleteButton">X</div>
```

Comment: Instead of deleting the value, delete <input> and add new <input> with only necessary attributes.